# How to adress a certain parameter of the element in the value of select in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML is following:

```
<tags>
      <tag id="2">
        <name>
          <de-DE>xxx</de-DE>
        </name>
      </tag>
      <tag id="5">
        <name>
          <de-DE>ccc</de-DE>
        </name>
      </tag>
      <tag id="12">
        <name>
          <de-DE>CC BY-SA</de-DE>
        </name>
      </tag>
    </tags>
```

I need to extract CC BY-SA from the tag id="12". How can I adress tag id="12" with a value of select command.
That's what I tried to do, but it extracts nothing:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="/tags/tag[@id=12]/name/de-DE"/>
```

Comment: can you post your xslt too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the XML you give as example, what you tried is correct. You can check it with any XSLT online tool.

However I entertain the possibility that the example you give is not exactly what you're working and trying with. For instance I imagine that your ids might be different (as when conforming with XML ID data type, simple numbers aren't valid as ids, they must be XML names.)

So something more like:

```
<tag id="id12">
  <name>
    <de-DE>CC BY-SA</de-DE>
  </name>
</tag>
```

and in that case, the id cannot be converted to number 12 anymore, and it can only be tested for equality with a string, which is 'id12'.

So the correct expression would be:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/tags/tag[@id='id12']/name/de-DE"/>
```

Comment: Other likely candidates for "things that people didn't tell us because they didn't realise it mattered" include (a) namespaces in the source document, and (b) the dynamic context of the xsl:value-of expression. It's always best to construct a complete runnable example that demonstrates the problem.